# Get data from array in JSON API object in Cypress

Tags: json, api, cypress

Relative newbie to Cypress and JSON data. I have an api online that I can access. The api has data similar to this:

```
{"record":[{"account":"acount_1","team":"Test 1","req_id":12345},{"account":"acount_2","team":"Test 2","req_id":23456}],"metadata":{"id":"abcde","private":false,"createdAt":"2022-12-21T00:00:00.000Z"}}
```

I am attempting to find a manner to get the amount of records that are in the api, as well as get the first team name.

The closest I have come to getting any kind of data is by using something like this:

```
    cy.get('@testing').then((data) => {
         for (let index in data)
             cy.log(data[index]) 
    })
```

However, all that does is show me what is in the API, not the data in the array itself. I have attempted dozens of different options, none of which has worked. I hope someone can please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your intercept was waited on with the alias and the data is nested as you say in the respon, you can access the response JSON data

```js
cy.get('@testing')
  // get records and check length
  .its('record')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  // get first team name
  .its('0.team')
  .should('eq', 'Test 1')
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/527cc884dd483fc6de872b1b68e94b8a2a4645f5/cypress/e2e/getObjectData.md).